# DataSet contents incorrect

Tags: asp.net, database

I'm populating a Repeater Control dynamically based on a querystring value.
On Page_Load, the page executes a function that gets info from the database and loads it into a DataSet is then used to populate the repeater.

The issue is that directly after truncating the table, it still appears to be returning a row...

Here's my code:

```
Private g As New Globals

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim CommentData As DataSet = g.GetComments(Request.QueryString("i"))
    ' Had the page tell me how many rows were in the table
    MsgBox(CommentData.Tables(0).Rows.Count.ToString)
    If CommentData.Tables(0).Rows.Count = 0 Then
        rptComments.Visible = False
    Else
        rptComments.DataSource = CommentData
        rptComments.DataBind()
    End If

' Heres g.GetComments()
Public Function GetComments(ByVal ArticleID As Integer) As DataSet
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT [CommentID], [Username] ,[Email] ,[URL] ,[CommentText] FROM Comments " & _
                        "WHERE ArticleID = " & ArticleID & " AND ApprovedYN = 'Yes' AND DeletedYN = 'No'"

    MyAdapter.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
    MyAdapter.Fill(MyData)

    Return MyData
End Function
```

The idea is that the Function will get all rows in the Comments table associated with the ArticleID passed to it from the QueryString, but I can't understand why it's returning a row when there aren't any in the table.

**EDIT**

I have another DataSet being created earlier and when I add the following, I get data from the 1st DataSet:

```
MsgBox(CommentData.Tables(0).Rows(0)(0).ToString)
```

I get the article's title which, as you can see from my code above, is not supposed to be in this DataSet...

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but important: concatenating ArticleID in your query leaves your database open to SQL Injection; you should parameterize it instead.

Comment: @jelbourn ~ You should also mention that he could use parameterized queries from right there in his code, by altering his SQL and adding about three more statements to his code. ;) ~ As for the actual question tho ... I've been staring at it, and if the table is really truncated, then there's some caching going on somewhere. What does a `<ctrl><f5>` show and how old is the data??

Comment: <ctrl><F5> makes no difference and the database is brand new (created it on Sunday 10/10/16) As for the parameters, I'm aware of the problems you guys mentioned, and I'll be changing that before the site goes live... For now it's just to speed up the actual dev

Comment: Check your connection string? Wouldn't be the first time I've seen someone connecting to the wrong database (or wrong SQL instance)

Comment: I copied the connection string out of the web.config file to be sure. It's being used everywhere else on the site and without errors...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!!!

Having created 2 DataSets in the same Sub seems to confuse something on the site...
All I did to fix the problem was to clear the first DataSet after having used it to populate my page's content areas, see the following:

```
If DataSet1 IsNot Nothing Then
    DataSet1.Clear()
End If

Dim DataSet2 As DataSet = g.GetComments(Request.QueryString("i"))
....
```